# Using "If cell contains" in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a macro where if there is a cell with the word "TOTAL" then it will input a dash in the cell below it. For example:

[image]

In the case above, I would want a dash in cell F7 (note: there could be any number of columns, so it will always be row 7 but not always column F).

I'm currently using this code, but it's not working and I can't figure out why.

```
Dim celltxt As String
Range("C6").Select
Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
celltxt = Selection.Text
If InStr(1, celltext, "TOTAL") > 0 Then
Range("C7").Select
Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
Selection.Value = "-"
End If
```

Help would be appreciated. Hopefully I'm not doing something stupid.

Comment: `it's not working and I can't figure out why` - *how* is it not working?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables There's no error message, but it just doesn't put a "-" in the cell (so the cell remains blank).

Comment: NEVER. EVER. USE. SELECT.

Comment: @Chrismas007 I'm new to VBA. Why should I never use .Select?

Comment: It is a waste of code.  See my answer below.  Basically it is redundant because you can combine the two lines and cut out a great deal of ambiguity. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This will loop through all cells in a given range that you define `("RANGE TO SEARCH")` and add dashes at the cell below using the `Offset()` method.  As a best practice in VBA, you should never use the `Select` method.

```
Sub AddDashes()

Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range

Set SrchRng = Range("RANGE TO SEARCH")

For Each cel In SrchRng
    If InStr(1, cel.Value, "TOTAL") > 0 Then
        cel.Offset(1, 0).Value = "-"
    End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C6:ZZ6")) Is Nothing Then

    If InStr(UCase(Target.Value), "TOTAL") > 0 Then
        Target.Offset(1, 0) = "-"
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

This will allow you to add columns dynamically and automatically insert a dash underneath any columns in the C row after 6 containing case insensitive "Total". Note: If you go past ZZ6, you will need to change the code, but this should get you where you need to go.

Answer (score 1):

This does the same, enhanced with CONTAINS:

```
Function SingleCellExtract(LookupValue As String, LookupRange As Range, ColumnNumber As Integer, Char As String)
Dim I As Long
Dim xRet As String
For I = 1 To LookupRange.Columns(1).Cells.Count
     If InStr(1, LookupRange.Cells(I, 1), LookupValue) > 0 Then
        If xRet = "" Then
            xRet = LookupRange.Cells(I, ColumnNumber) & Char
        Else
            xRet = xRet & "" & LookupRange.Cells(I, ColumnNumber) & Char
        End If
    End If
Next
SingleCellExtract = Left(xRet, Len(xRet) - 1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim celltxt As String
Range("C6").Select
Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
celltxt = Selection.Text
If InStr(1, celltext, "TOTAL") > 0 Then
Range("C7").Select 
Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
Selection.Value = "-"
End If
```

You declared "celltxt" and used "celltext" in the instr.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
 If ActiveCell.Value == "Total" Then

    ActiveCell.offset(1,0).Value = "-"

 End If
```

Of you could do something like this

```
 Dim celltxt As String
 celltxt = ActiveSheet.Range("C6").Text
 If InStr(1, celltxt, "Total") Then
    ActiveCell.offset(1,0).Value = "-"
 End If
```

Which is similar to what you have.

Answer (score 0):

**Requirement:**
Find a cell containing the word `TOTAL` then to enter a dash in the cell below it.

**Solution:**
This solution uses the `Find` method of the `Range` object, as it seems appropriate to use it rather than brute force (`For…Next` loop).
For explanation and details about the method see [Range.Find method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)

**Implementation:**
In order to provide flexibility the `Find` method is wrapped in this function:

```
Function Range_ƒFind_Action(sWhat As String, rTrg As Range) As Boolean
```

Where:
    `sWhat`: contains the `string` to search for
    `rTrg`: is the `range` to be searched

The function returns `True` if any match is found, otherwise it returns `False`

Additionally, every time the function finds a match it passes the resulting `range` to the procedure `Range_Find_Action` to execute the required action, (i.e. *"enter a dash in the cell below it"*). The *"required action"* is in a separated procedure to allow for customization and flexibility.

This is how the function is called:

This test is searching for "total" to show the effect of the `MatchCase:=False`. The match can be made case sensitive by changing it to `MatchCase:=True`

```
Sub Range_Find_Action_TEST()
Dim sWhat As String, rTrg As Range
Dim sMsgbdy As String
    sWhat = "total"                                             'String to search for (update as required)
    Rem Set rTrg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sht(0)").UsedRange  'Range to Search (use this to search all used cells)
    Set rTrg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sht(0)").Rows(6)        'Range to Search (update as required)
    sMsgbdy = IIf(Range_ƒFind_Action(sWhat, rTrg), _
        "Cells found were updated successfully", _
        "No cells were found.")
    MsgBox sMsgbdy, vbInformation, "Range_ƒFind_Action"
    End Sub
```

This is the *Find* function

```
Function Range_ƒFind_Action(sWhat As String, rTrg As Range) As Boolean
Dim rCll As Range, s1st As String
    With rTrg

        Rem Set First Cell Found
        Set rCll = .Find(What:=sWhat, After:=.Cells(1), _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        Rem Validate First Cell
        If rCll Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        s1st = rCll.Address

        Rem Perform Action
        Call Range_Find_Action(rCll)

        Do
            Rem Find Other Cells
            Set rCll = .FindNext(After:=rCll)
            Rem Validate Cell vs 1st Cell
            If rCll.Address <> s1st Then Call Range_Find_Action(rCll)

        Loop Until rCll.Address = s1st

    End With

    Rem Set Results
    Range_ƒFind_Action = True

    End Function
```

This is the *Action* procedure

```
Sub Range_Find_Action(rCll)
    rCll.Offset(1).Value2 = Chr(167)    'Update as required - Using `§` instead of "-" for visibilty purposes
    End Sub
```

[image]