# If and Loop function to extract data

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Sample Dataset]

In the sample dataset above, I am trying to use the VBA's **If** function to look for a specific keyword, and if there's a match, I would want to extract the Name itself, alongside its Serial Number and Product, and add to the last row of another worksheet, within the same workbook.

For instance, **If** in column C, we detect, say, **cana** (note that this is not an exact match, but good enough), then I would want VBA to help me to extract **Canary Wharf**, its **Serial Number** and **Product** next to it, which are **8273615** and **Canned Food**, to the end of another worksheet, and the loop goes on until the end of Canary Wharf and moves on to Riverdale, which I would type, say, **riverd**, and repeat the same process. The x's are there to signify that I have a rather large dataset, nothing else.

I have gotten some clues with the top answer found in [Using "If cell contains" in VBA excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27426835/using-if-cell-contains-in-vba-excel) , it is of great help, but I could not quite get the exact thing to do.
Any help would be very much appreciated!

Below should be the intuition:

```
Option Compare Text

Sub DataExtraction()

Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")


Set SrchRng = ws1.Range("C:C")

For Each cel In SrchRng
    If InStr(1, cel.Value, "cana") > 0 Then
        ActiveCell.Value = "Canary Wharf"

    End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

By using the code above, I managed to get the ActiveCell.Value to become Canary Wharf, however, I need the code to loop until there are no more Canary Wharf's, and at the same time, also copy the two inputs to its right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Option Compare Text

Sub DataExtraction()

    Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range, rngDest as Range
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    'restrict the search range
    Set SrchRng = Application.Intersect(ws1.Range("C:C"), ws.UsedRange)

    Set rngDest = ws2.cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 'start copy here

    For Each cel In SrchRng.Cells
        If InStr(1, cel.Value, "cana") > 0 Then
            rngDest.Value = "Canary Wharf"
            rngDest.offset(0, 1).value = cel.offset(0, 1).value
            rngDest.offset(0, 2).value = cel.offset(0, 2).value
            Set rngDest = rngDest.offset(1, 0) '<< next row down
        End If
    Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: Tim, I cannot thank you enough for your contribution. If it is not too much to ask, could I draw your expertise on a similar question posted here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60770362/if-and-loop-function .

Comment: Looks like you already have a good answer there.  No need for loops when you have built-in functions which already do this quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a userform to input what you wanna find and use range.find

```
Dim C as Integer

C = Range("C:C").Find(Userform1.Value).Row
```