# VBA Look down column to find specific criteria then SUM cell after criteria met cell

Tags: excel, vba

Currently, I'm trying to figure a way to look down a single column to find a specific criterion and in this case, I want to find dates that are less than 4/16/20. Once that criteria is met, I want to SUM the cell below for all met criteria in that column. This is an image of my dataset

[image: Dataset].

After doing some googling the closest I found was the code below which leads me to the idea that change information after offset to compute what I want.

[Using "If cell contains" in VBA excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27426835/using-if-cell-contains-in-vba-excel)

```
Sub AddDashes()

Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range

Set SrchRng = Range("RANGE TO SEARCH")

For Each cel In SrchRng
   If InStr(1, cel.Value, "TOTAL") > 0 Then
      cel.Offset(1, 0).Value = "-"
   End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

Not sure if I'm on the right track. It would also be nice If I would be able to amend code to check a range vs 1 column, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example you need to select the range of dates (1 row at a time only) to run the code. This also allows you to input the date (I'm assuming it changes over time so this should be helpful)

```
Sub SumByDate()

Dim DateRange As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim d As Range
Dim SearchDateInput As String
Dim SearchDate As Date

Set DateRange = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Get Range", Type:=8) 'Select Date Range
SearchDateInput = Application.InputBox("Enter A Date") 'enter as mm/dd/yyyy
SearchDate = DateValue(SearchDateInput) 'this converts date entered as string to date format


For Each c In SrchRng 'for each date in list of dates
Set d = c.Offset(1, 0) 'pionts out cells to sum- in this case the cell beneath the date
   If c < SearchDate Then 'if date is less than input date
      Sum = Sum + d 'sum the date if true
   End If
Next c 'goes to next date in row

DateRange.Cells(1, 1).Offset(2, -1) = Sum 'inputs all summed values into cell that is two down, one to the left of first date cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub SumByDate()

Dim SrchRng As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim d As Range
Dim lCol As Long
Dim ColLtr As String
Dim SearchDate As Date

lCol = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
ColLtr = Split(Cells(1, lCol).Address, "$")(1)
Set SrchRng = Range("B2:" & ColLtr & "2")
SearchDate = DateValue("04/16/2020")


For Each c In SrchRng
Set d = c.Offset(1, 0)
   If c < SearchDate Then
      Sum = Sum + d
   End If
Next c

Range("A4") = Sum

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked but only for row two (2). I wanted to know how to do what you did for row two (2) but for Col B. Would you be able to add annotations. So I get a better understanding and maybe explain myself better. I like this method too, to calculate individual customers, but I would also like to calculate for all, either in a column or range like B:H, thanks.

Comment: @FreddyMondragon you can declare each range separately but that would be time-consuming, especially if your ranges change. Perhaps dialog box to select range is better? I'm posting an idea with explanations as a new answer.