# Automatically check a checkbox when a different checkbox is checked excel

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

So I just discovered the developer tab on excel and am having trouble trying to work with checkboxes.

I have a sheet with locations that can be checked twice
[image]

To keep track of some things, I have the usual linked cell next to the checkbox to say TRUE or FALSE to count them, as well as some cosmetic conditional formatting.

Now, what I want to do is: whenever you check the checkbox on the right, the checkbox on the left should be checked as well, but not the opposite.

I've been reading and reading but can't find a solution to this specifically. What I found that was most similar was this, but it didn't work with me (trying to change FALSE to TRUE) [link to stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27426835/using-if-cell-contains-in-vba-excel)

Thank you in advance to anyone who has any idea how to do this, or has a link to an already answered question i could have missed!

PS: I know absolutely nothing about VBA, it's the first time I've used it. Also this is just a project on the side for a checklist, nothing serious but I figured I could make it pretty. I do know a bit of C# but I doubt it's helping.

Comment: It appears that you have MANY checkboxes. You will need to have separate code event procedures for EACH textbox on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `checkbox1` on the left, and `checkbox2` on the right, and you want `checkbox1` to be selected when `checkbox2` is selected on:

[image]

Enable design mode first and right click on the `checkbox2` and go to `view code`

[image]

Assign this code, then disable `design mode` and it shall work:

```
Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
If CheckBox2.Value = True Then
    CheckBox1.Value = True
End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately I had tried this before as it's one of the first seolutions that come up, but it doesn't work. It throws the error: `runtime error 424 object required`

Comment: First thing, did you name the `checkbox` property and write in the same using the same name? Second, check my edited answer for the library reference , those are basic library you should have. If this not working, try show your `checkbox name` using `property` in your question